# Visual Studio 2015 recent projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just did a fresh install of Windows 10 and installed Visual Studio 2015. Everything is working fine, but strangely, it does not fill the "Recent Projects" section on my start page. It just stays empty. Taskbar recent-used-list is working though.

Max. recent projects is set to 10, I can confirm this with regedit under this path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\MRUItems\{a9c4a31f-f9cb-47a9-abc0-49ce82d0b3ac}\Items
```

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was:
I used the program XP-AntiSpy to deactivate certain functions. One of those functions turned out to be the function that creates a list of recently used files (appearantly for every program, not only for windows). After re-activating this function, everything started to work fine again.